# How to replace </br> and <br/> with \n?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to replace `</br>` and `<br/>` with `\n`?

With this there are many answers. People do some mistake in writing break tag.

Anwers for all above two types of break are mentioned below.

Comment: Why do you have `</br>`? That is not valid HTML.

Comment: @putvande — Quoting the question: "People do some mistake in writing break tag."

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Missed that bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
yourString.replace(/(<br>|<\/br>|<br \/>)/mgi, "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 "Hello<br/>World".replace(/<br\s*\/?>/ig, "\r\n");
 "Hello</br>World".replace(/<\s*\/?br>/ig, "\r\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function br2nl(str) {
    return str.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/mg,"\n");
}
```

call like below

```
br2nl("Hello<br/>World");
```

SEE **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/9QEtz/1/)**